# Maven's dependency:purge-local-repository doesn't delete local repository

Tags: maven, maven-2

I have seen many posts regarding this, but none seem to do what I want.

I want the command

```
$ mvn dependency:purge-local-repository -DreResolve=false -DactTransitively=true
```

to have the same effect on my project as running 
`rm -rf` in the .m2/repository directory, but only for the project where I'm running the maven command on. However, it seems like that command actually downloads these dependencies rather than delete them.

My Maven version output:

```
Maven home: /Users/noelsaldanha/Software/apache-maven-3.6.3
Java version: 14.0.1, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_MO, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.14.6", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

I'm not sure if it could be a bug or something to that sort, but I've tried many variations of the `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` command and none of them deleted my local repository.

Comment: Please read the docs carefully: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/purge-local-repository-mojo.html It does not delete the whole local repository only the artifacts from within the given project or explicit the given artifacts..Why not using `rm -fr .m2/repository`?

Comment: Because I'm only interested in deleting the project's dependencies, and not all dependencies from other projects. I have read the documentation carefully, but unfortunately it's not what happens when I do exactly was they say, or try other variations of the command

Comment: The other question is: Why do you need to purge the locate cache? Do you use `mvn .. install`? If so this is the wrong part..never use install...